# How to launch the SQL Server service in browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, localhost, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server. I am doing the offline sync using SQL Server and sqlite DB. For that I followed the below tutorial [SQL Server Installation](http://sqlite-sync.com/documentation/installation/). In this tutorial I am stuck on how to open the localhost service. When I run the service (`localhost/AuroraSyncService.svc`) in browser it shows empty.

For this I created the database `AuroraSyncCn` in my SQL Server Management Studio and created the new website in my IIS (internet information security).

MY coneection Strings:

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="AuroraSyncCn" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SQLite-Sync.com;User ID=sa;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

here i tried  `connectionString="localhost/myservicefolde/aurorasyncservice.asmx;`

Somebody help to solve this one.

Comment: Change the localhost to IP ADDRESS and check

Comment: @VijayHulmani thanks for your reply..i changed but not get..one more i  use index.html (like localhost/index.html) in that folder it work perfectly when go the service it shows empty...can you help to solve this...

Comment: How is your web.config look like? I think the problem maybe with connection string.

Comment: @vasin1987 look at my connection strings...

Comment: @Arut are you using sqlserver express? if yes the instance name would be yourcomputer\SQLExpress Also the initial catalog looks weird to me. It might work if you warp it in []

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your connection string should contain your database name (Initial Catalog=AuroraSyncCn).
If it's SQLExpress, instance name should probably be the same as the one mentioned by vasin1987 (server/serverinstance).
But from what I remember from ASP.NET, 'localhost' as Data Source should also be just fine.

Can you please show/write what you have in login window in MS SQL (Server name is what interest us the most):

[image]